# Can the variance exist without sample space and probability measure function?

Tags: probability, variance

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance **variance** is related to random variable. Random Variable is defined in terms of sample space and probability measure function.

> In probability theory and statistics, variance is the expectation of
>   the squared deviation of a random variable from its mean.

The https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation.html site defines **variance** without any relation to random variable.

Does this mean variance is a property on the set of data and since random variable represents a set of data, variance is defined over it ?

Comment: This is the sample variance, it is merely an estimator of the variance and can be computed from the sample. There could be other estimators for the variance but this one have the advantage to be unbiased and is actually considered a good one for example if the data have normal distribution.

Comment: Is the "sample variance" different from the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance ?